# Question about proof characterisation partial isometry

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, c-star-algebras, isometry

Consider the following fragment in the text "$C^*$-algebras and operator theory by Murphy":

[image: ry]

Could someone explain why the marked step is true? I don't see how this follows from $\Vert u(x) \Vert^2 = \Vert u^* u(x) \Vert^2$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $\|u(x)\|^2 = \|u^*u(x)\|^2$ for all $x$ then $\|u(1-u^*u)\,(x)\|^2=\|u^*u(1-u^*u)\,(x)\|^2=\|(u^*u-(u^*u)^2)\,(x)\|^2$. But $u^*u$ is a projection so what is left here is $\|(u^*u-u^*u)\,(x)\|^2=0$.

Comment: Thanks @s.harp. Please consider making this an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\|u(x)\|^2 = \|u^*u(x)\|^2$ for all $x$ then $\|u(1-u^*u)\,(x)\|^2=\|u^*u(1-u^*u)\,(x)\|^2=\|(u^*u-(u^*u)^2)\,(x)\|^2$. But $u^*u$ is a projection so what is left here is $\|u(1-u^*u)\,(x)\|^2=\|(u^*u-u^*u)\,(x)\|^2=0$ for all $x$.